# Adding pagenumbers to journalcitation with postnotes and incollection citations in biblatex windycity style

Tags: biblatex, windycity

In the windycity style of biblatex, you don't get page numbers in the first citation of journal articles if there is a postnote, or of chapters in collections at all. How can I make sure that the page numbers always show in the full citation of articles and chapters?

The MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=windycity, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}
    \cite{shore}
    
    \cite[2]{glashow}
    
    \cite{westfahl:space}
\end{document}
```

now produces:

> Bradd Shore, “Twice-Born, Once Conceived: Meaning Construction and
> Cultural Cognition,” American Anthropologist, new ser., 93, no. 1
> (March 1991): 9–27.
>
> Sheldon Glashow, “Partial Symmetries of Weak
> Interactions,” Nucl. Phys. 22 (1961): 2.
>
> Gary Westfahl, “The True
> Frontier: Confronting and Avoiding the Realities of Space in American
> Science Fiction Films,” in, in Space and BeyondSpace and Beyond: The
> Frontier Theme in Science Fiction, ed. Gary Westfahl (Westport, Conn.
> Greenwood, 2000).

but I want it to produce:

> Bradd Shore, “Twice-Born, Once Conceived: Meaning Construction and
> Cultural Cognition,” American Anthropologist, new ser., 93, no. 1
> (March 1991): 9–27.
>
> Sheldon Glashow, “Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions,” *Nucl.
> Phys.* 22 (1961): 579-588, 2.
>
> Gary Westfahl, “The True Frontier:
> Confronting and Avoiding the Realities of Space in American Science
> Fiction Films,” in, in Space and BeyondSpace and Beyond: The Frontier
> Theme in Science Fiction, ed. Gary Westfahl, 55-65 (Westport, Conn.
> Greenwood, 2000).

(the incollection citation is a bit wonky because windycity uses different fields than standard biblatex styles but I wanted to use biblatex-examples as bib file for easy of use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to chase the `pages` and `postnote` fields through the bibmacros and bibliography drivers in `windycity.cbx` and `windycity.bbx`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=windycity, sorting=nyt]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{cite:article}{%
  \usebibmacro{author+title+etc}%
  \usebibmacro{articles}%
  \usebibmacro{colon+pages+etc}}%

\renewbibmacro*{cite:pages}{}

\renewbibmacro*{pages}{%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {}
    {\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \printfield{pages}%
     \clearfield{pages}%
     \togglefalse{edshift}}}

\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iffieldundef{postnote}
    {}
    {\setunit{\postnotedelim}%
     \printtext[bibhyperref]{\printfield{postnote}}}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}
  \cite{shore}

  \cite[2]{glashow}

  \cite{westfahl:space}

  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Bradd Shore, “Twice-Born, Once Conceived: Meaning Construction and Cultural Cognition,” American Anthropologist, new ser., 93, no. 1 (March 1991): 9–27.//Sheldon Glashow, “Partial Symmetries of Weak Interactions,” Nucl. Phys. 22 (1961): 579–588, 2.//Gary Westfahl, “The True Frontier: Confronting and Avoiding the Realities of Space in American Science Fiction Films,” in, in Space and Beyond Space and Beyond: The Frontier Theme in Science Fiction, ed. Gary Westfahl, 55–65 (Westport, Conn. Greenwood, 2000).]

Comment: With the current solution, the pages for an `@incollection` entry will appear before the volume number in case the collection consists of multiple volumes. can this be reversed?

for example the bibentry

`@InCollection{CDSB-Pannekoek, author = {Minnaert}, crossref = {CDSB}, pages = {289--291}, title = {Pannekoek}, volume = {10}, date = {2008}, booktitle = {CDSB}, location = {Detroit}, publisher = {CSS}}`

now produces 'Minnaert, “Pannekoek,” in CDSB, 289-291, vol. 10 (Detroit: CSS, 2008)' but I want it to produce 'Minnaert, “Pannekoek,” in CDSB, vol. 10, 289-291 (Detroit: CSS, 2008)'.

Comment: @cktai Mhh, that looks like a bit of work: The relevant macros in `windycity` are nested quite deeply and possibly interconnected in many places. I can't offer a quick solution in the comments now. You may have a better chance of getting an answer if you ask a new question with a full MWE. Then other people could have a look as well.

Comment: I was afraid that may be the case. I tried to figure it out myself but got lost in the code.

Separate question is here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/575635/change-the-order-of-volume-and-pagenumbers-fir-incollection-entry-in-windycity