# Change the order of volume and pagenumbers for @incollection entry in windycity

Tags: biblatex, windycity

Currently, `@incollection` entries in the `windycity` style of `biblatex` will place pagenumbers before the volume. This makes sense when you have `@mvcollection`s with a `maintitle` and separate `booktitle`s, but not so much for `mvcollection`s under a single name. How can I change this around?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[style=windycity]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{biblio.bib}
    @incollection{entry,
        title = {Chapter},
        author = {Author},
        location = {Place},
        publisher = {Publisher},
        date = {2020},
        volume = {1},
        pages = {100--110},
        booktitle = {Book},
        editora = {Editor}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\bibliography{biblio}
\begin{document}
   \nocite{entry}
   \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

produces:

> Author. “Chapter.” In Book, edited by Editor, 100–110. Vol. 1. Place: Publisher, 2020.

but I want it to produce:

> Author. “Chapter.” In Book, edited by Editor. Vol. 1, 100-110. Place: Publisher, 2020.

How can this be changed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making changes to a complex style like `windycity` can be risky since it's meant to closely follow Chicago style.

I've tried to avoid side effects, but you should be careful.

I've made three changes to the `volumes+bookseries+etc` and `volume+number+etc` macros to swap the `pages` and `volumes` field when there is no `bookbooktitle` field.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[style=windycity]{biblatex}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{biblio.bib}
@incollection{entry,
  title = {Chapter},
  author = {Author},
  location = {Place},
  publisher = {Publisher},
  date = {2020},
  volume = {1},
  pages = {100--110},
  booktitle = {Book},
  editora = {Editor}
}
@InCollection{doe2018,
    author = {Doe, Jane},
    title = {A Poem},
    translator = {Smith, John},
    pages = {56-57},
    crossref = {jones2018}
}
@InBook{jones2018,
    editor = {Jones, David},
    title = {A Volume of Poems},
    volume = {2},
    year = {2018},
    crossref = {blow2016}   
}
@Collection{blow2016,
    editor = {White, Amy},
    title = {A Collection of Poems},
    volumes = {4},
    address = {Chicago},
    publisher = ucp,
    year = {2018}
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\renewbibmacro*{volumes+bookseries+etc}{%
  \usebibmacro{volumes}%
  \usebibmacro{bookseries}%
  \iffieldundef{bookbooktitle}% <-- edit
    {}%                         <-- edit
    {\usebibmacro{pages}}%      <-- edit
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+etc}%
  \usebibmacro{book:number}%
  \usebibmacro{part}}%
\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+etc}{%
  \iffieldundef{\xvolume volume}
    {}
    {\iffieldundef{bookbooktitle}%    <-- edit
       {}%                            <-- edit
       {\usebibmacro{swapvol+pages}}% <-- edit
     \iffieldundef{series}
       {\newunit}%
       {\setunit{\addcomma\space}}%
     \iffieldnum{\xvolume volume}
       {\printfield[volume]{\xvolume volume}%
        \usebibmacro{volume:number}}%
       {\bibstring{volumes}\space
        \printfield[noformat]{\xvolume volume}}%
     \clearfield{\xvolume volume}%
     \usebibmacro{part}%
     \iffieldundef{bookbooktitle}% <-- edit
       {\usebibmacro{pages}}%      <-- edit
       {}%                         <-- edit
     \iftoggle{collection}
       {\iftoggle{swapvol}
          {\addcomma\space}%
          {\space\bibstring{of}\space}}%
       {\iffieldundef{maintitle}
          {}
          {\space\bibstring{of}\space}}}}
\begin{document}
\nocite{entry,doe2018}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Works like a charm for my purposes, but I don't have any books as part of a multivolume collection so I can't check if it doesn't break anything there. Windycity is amazing at following the examples that CMOS provides, but even if that vast amount of examples, there is still some ambiguity left, for example in this case. All the triggers needed for various cases makes it too obscure for me to figure it out myself.